# "He plays games in/at/using his laptop"

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct?

> He plays games **in** his laptop.
>
> He plays games **at** his laptop.
>
> He plays games **using** his laptop.

Comment: I would say, “He plays games ***on*** his laptop/computer/GameBoy/phone/PSP/whatever”.

Comment: "He plays games *with* his laptop" is common as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The form I have encountered is:-
He plays games *on* his laptop.
I don't particularly know why - it just seems idiomatic.

Of the three versions you have suggested, the first sounds wrong, as it suggests he is inside his computer.  I would argue that the second and third are both correct, though the third has a subtle difference in meaning.

Comment: If I was to hazard a guess as to why "on" is the appropriate word, I'd say that it's because, conceptually speaking, computer architecture tends to be thought of as a series of layers. Applications like games are at the highest level and therefore run "on" the platform and layers beneath.

Comment: No, idiomatically, this usage predates computers - think "on the phone" - and is used in a similar manner to "on the road" or "on the way", implying position of the subject.

Comment: The second sounds incorrect when used with an action verb like "plays"; it sounds OK to say "he is at is laptop" or even "he is sitting at his laptop", but "he is playing games at his laptop" sounds like the action of playing games is being directed *towards* the laptop.

Answer (score 4):

Although everybody already said that the correct usage is "He plays games on his laptop", I'd like to offer up a suggestion as to why that is.

One also says, "I'm **on** the computer" which I would say comes from the earlier saying "I'm logged on the computer".

I think the usage of **on** comes with the fact that one is **on** the computer, not with *at* or *in*.

Responding to "He plays games using his laptop" - This isn't normal, but could be fine depending on context.

Comment: +1 for mentioning how context might alter what sounds acceptable. At first glance, "He plays games using his laptop" sounds a bit unnatural to me. However, that could change, depending on the conversation. Consider this set-up: "Wow, this is an old computer! I can't believe your son plays games on this." "Oh, he doesn't. He plays games using his laptop." Suddenly, that sounds more acceptable for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

I would agree, the most common form is "He plays games on his laptop" or "He plays on his XBOX." But, there is nothing wrong with "He plays games using his laptop."

While idiomatic, neither "in" nor "at" would sound right in most English dialects.

Comment: Your last sentence does not make any sense. If ‘in’ and ‘at’ do not sound right, they are not idiomatic—that is basically the definition of idiomaticness.

Comment: Most of us don't play games "in" the laptop – except maybe [Tron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tron).

Answer (score 2):

He plays games *with* his laptop = He plays games *using* his laptop. **No** (*Not really*)

If you play games *using* your laptop, (which is fine grammatically speaking), to me it sounds weird. I imagine the speaker whacking a ball with his laptop. The laptop is being used as a tool, an instrument with which to play games. What you could say instead is:

- He uses his laptop ***to play*** games (on). (This helps explains the purpose of the laptop)
- He uses the laptop ***for*** playing games. (This helps explains the function of the laptop)

The only sentence NOT from the list which carries no ambiguity is the following:

- He plays games **on** his laptop.

Comment: “He plays games using his laptop” does not automatically carry this connotation to me, though I can see where your interpretation is coming from. When you play a game on a machine, you are also using it as an instrument to play the game, just in a different way than an actual sports implement. “He plays games using his laptop” and “He uses his laptop to play games” are synonymous in this sense to me—both can be taken to mean he’s using his laptop to whack the ball, but neither is likely to actually mean that.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Being a pedantic person(!), I could say that if "play[ing] games *with* his laptop" = "whacking a ball with his laptop", then "play[ing] games *on* his laptop" = "laying out the playing cards *on* his laptop", so it is not unambiguous!! ;-)

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I was only pointing out that your reply made it seem like the ‘racquet’ interpretation was the immediate, automatic one for the phrase with ‘using’, which it isn’t. I have nothing against light-heartedness here or on any other SE site (I make plenty of jokes here myself), as long as they don’t end up misleading others, which I felt this answer might.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I wish to apologize for my rudeness. It is not your fault. We all have lives outside ELU and sometimes what happens outside effects how we see and read other people's comments. Please, accept my deepest apologies. I will now delete the comment, and I hope we can remain good "colleagues".

Comment: @Mari-LouA, no hard feelings. I just hope I don’t come across as someone who follows people around, pointing out their flaws for the fun of it. If I do point things out, it is only to ensure that the best possible answers are given. :-)